# Makefile No such directory or file error

Tags: c, makefile

```
# Set the flags for the C compiler
CFLAGS= -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
# Build rule for the final executable
ass.exe: assemble.o branch.o dataProcessing.o multiply.o singleDataTransfer.o special.o
    $(CC) $ˆ -o $@
# Build rules for the .o files
assemble.o: assemble.c dataProcessing.h multiply.h singleDataTransfer.h special.h branch.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
branch.o: branch.c branch.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
dataProcessing.o: dataProcessing.c dataProcessing.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
multiply.o: multiply.c multiply.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
singleDataTransfer.o: singleDataTransfer.c singleDataTransfer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
special.o: special.c special.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
# Rule to clean generated files
clean:
    rm -f 
# Tell make that ‘clean’ is not a real file
.PHONY: clean
```

This is the makefile file I have. But the final executable file cannot be created although all the other .o file can be created and I can use those .o file created by this makefile to compile an executable file in terminal.
Could someone give some advice on how to correct the mistake in my makefile?

This is the error message:

```
cc � -o ass.exe
cc: error: �: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ass.exe] Error 4
```

Comment: Err, `ass.exe`??! You'd better rename the executable.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message ? Edit the question and add it at the bottom.

Comment: OK! I have added the detailed error message. This is saying the file does not exist.

Comment: For the rule about the executable, you should use the `LINK.c` variable instead of `CC`, because it takes many useful other options variables into account.

From `make -p`, it is defined as 
`LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)`

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that you have an encoding problem.  You should be using the ASCII character `^` (ASCII code 94) when you add the `$^` to your recipe.  You instead have introduced some other character which is a multibyte character, for your `$^`.  This causes make to take the first byte of the character and treat it as a variable name and expand it, which yields an empty string, and the second byte is left as-is and becomes an illegal character, hence the strange character in the output line.

Change your:

```
$(CC) $ˆ -o $@
```

to:

```
$(CC) $^ -o $@
```

and it will work.

Comment: Good catch. +1. The `ˆ` character that the OP is using is [MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02c6/index.htm).